# Autohotkey Recursion Function And Return

Tags: javascript, recursion, return, combinations, autohotkey

The autohotkey code and the javascript code are the same 100% code.

But the results are quite different.

Could you tell me why?

javascript result

```
 4 5 6 

 3 5 6 

 2 5 6 

 1 5 6 

 3 4 6 

 2 4 6 

 1 4 6 

 2 3 6 

 1 3 6 

 1 2 6 

 3 4 5 

 2 4 5 

 1 4 5 

 2 3 5 

 1 3 5 

 1 2 5 

 2 3 4 

 1 3 4 

 1 2 4 

 1 2 3
```

autohotkey result

```
 4 5 6 

 3 5 6 

 2 5 6 

 1 5 6
```

Code:

```
//////////////////

combi(n, r, arr, sz){ 
Global
i:=n+1
while ( i-->r ) { 

arr[r - 1]:=i
if (r > 1) {
combi(i - 1, r - 1, arr, sz)
} else { 

j:= -1
while ( ++j<sz ) {
result.=arr[j] " "
} 
result.="`n"
} 
} 
} ; combi()

result:=""
N:= 6
M:= 3
arr:= Object()
arr.Insert([])
combi(N,M,arr,M)
MsgBox, % result

//////////////////////////////////////

<html> 
<head> 
<script> 
result="";
var N = 10; 
var M = 3; 
var arr = new Array(M); 
combi(N,M,arr,M);
alert(result);

function combi(n, r, arr, sz){ 
var i=n+1;
while(i-->r){ 
// choose the first element 
arr[r - 1] = i; 
if (r > 1) { // if still needs to choose 
// recursive into smaller problem 
combi(i - 1, r - 1, arr, sz); 
// return combi(i - 1, r - 1, arr, sz); 
} else { 
// print out one solution 
var j = -1;
while(++j<sz){
result+=arr[j] + " "; 
} 
result+="\n"; 
} 
} 
} 

</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Load your JavaScript code into a debugger like the Chrome DevTools. Load your AutoHotkey code into SciTE4AutoHotkey. Now single step through both versions of the code, side by side; JavaScript in the browser and AutoHotkey in SciTE4AutoHotkey. Use "step in" at each step, not "step over". You will soon find where they go different from each other.

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot of you.